# PHP DOM: Get all text values

Tags: php, text, html-parsing, domdocument

I've got an HTML string that might look something like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <span class="blah">Monkey </span>
    <p>breath really <b>stinks</b></p>
    And I don't like it!
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, there's some text contained properly as a value inside of an element, there's elements that contain text nodes and other elements.  I would like to be able to get **all the text values** under body (assume body is a DOMElement that I have stored in a variable).

So, the output would look something like:

> Monkey breat really stinks And I don't like it!

How would I do this?  XPath?  Regexps?  Magic?

Comment: Try magic, when it feels, you use javascript.

Comment: @jwegner - why do you want do this ? what's the use case?

Comment: @Flukey Similar to "link density" as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652657/what-algorithm-does-readability-use-for-extracting-text-from-urls), I would like to calculate the <img> density for an HTML form

Comment: @Chibuzo, I've been trying magic, but I keep getting syntax errors.  Also, can't use javascript because the HTML is loaded into PHP via cURL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jquery, I might have an answer for this.

First we need to crawl the content.So use php curl for that and echo the content.After you get the content in the body trigger a jquery function which has the following line,

supposing all the text is contained in a div with id content

```
$('#content').text() gives you the required output.
```

Remember to use jquery delegate to bind the function to whatever the event you choose.

Comment: This is inside of PHP, and the HTML is gather via cURL.  Unfortunately jQuery is not an option.

Comment: I am using the same thing daily. I will just edit this answer to give you a complete picture

Comment: No, really, this can't be done in the frontend.  There literally _is no_ frontend.  Think of this as being a sort of API function - something that runs entirely on the server, and the parsed result is passed to the user via JSON.