# Better method of checking a bunch of conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and still coming to terms with the language's nuances.

I have a piece of code where I have to check a set of conditions on a particular variable.

```
if (a=="MAIN_DOMAINNAME" || a=="DOMAIN_SERIAL" || a=="DOMAIN_REFRESH" || a=="DOMAIN_RETRY" || a=="DOMAIN_EXPIRE" || a=="DOMAIN_NEGTTL" || a=="MAIN_NS") {
```

Is there a better way to do this conditional check, like say:

`if a is one of ("DOMAIN_SERIAL", "MAIN_DOMAINNAME", "DOMAIN_REFRESH" ) {`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming a relatively modern browser, you can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) [(spec)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14)

```
if (["DOMAIN_SERIAL", "MAIN_DOMAINNAME", "DOMAIN_REFRESH"].indexOf(a) !== -1)
```

Note - you can easily shim it for older browsers (see [the mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on how).

Comment: 8 upvotes within a minute for such a trivial answer O_o (and none on the question).

Comment: @RobW What can I say? Simpler questions help more users in SO than more complicated and specific ones. If it makes you feel any better I have some answers that are 5 pages long and cite new concepts from multiple recent articles - I guess not many people found stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15648868/1348195) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A regex would be shorter and works everywhere :

```
if ( /^(MAIN_DOMAINNAME|DOMAIN_SERIAL|DOMAIN_REFRESH|..)$/.test(a) ) {
   // do stuff
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHXXU/2/)

Comment: This is not equivalent. Don't forget the ^ and $.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ars = ["DOMAIN_SERIAL", "MAIN_DOMAINNAME", "DOMAIN_REFRESH"];
if(ars.some(function(ar){ return a === ar; })){
     // do smth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should mention the switch statement as it should be working fine with the example given in the question.

```
switch(a) {
  case('MAIN_DOMAINAME'):
  case('DOMAIN_SERIAL'):
  case('DOMAIN_REFRESH'):
  case('DOMAIN_RETRY'):
    console.log('Go wild.');
  break;
}
```

Not as lightweight as the other answers, but it's readable and matches (a === b).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the regex solution already provided by adeneo, but if you want something that matches the

```
if a is one of (...
```

wording from the question reasonably closely you can do this:

```
if (a in list("MAIN_DOMAINNAME", "DOMAIN_SERIAL", "DOMAIN_REFRESH", "DOMAIN_RETRY")) {
    // do something                 (rest of list omitted to avoid scrolling)
}
```

by providing a helper function to turn the list into an object:

```
function list() {
   var o={}, i;
   for (i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) o[arguments[i]] = true;
   return o;
}
```

Of course you can omit the helper function and just use an object literal, but that's ugly:

```
if (a in {"MAIN_DOMAINNAME":1, "DOMAIN_SERIAL":1, "DOMAIN_REFRESH":1}) {
```