# Rules to pull reader-view like content from website?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm trying to implement my own little reader view app (an app that would do the same thing as reader-mode on safari), and there are a few things I find asking myself:

- Is there a technical term for this feature (reader-view doesn't really cut it)?
- Is there a standard that websites are supposed to follow in order to indicate the content they would like to have in their reader views
- Is there an open-source set of HTML parsing rules to pull the "readable" content from a website?
- Is the effort to implement such a thing simply too big for a single person in a few weeks and if so should I opt for services such as Instaparser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the original to be implemented by arc90, and they called it readability. You can check out their page [here](http://www.arc90.com/work/readability/).

It's been ported to many different languages over time, so you could take a look at the different implementations to learn more about it, how it's done etc.

- [Python readability](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability)
- [JReadability](https://github.com/wuman/JReadability)
- [JavaScript](https://github.com/mozilla/readability)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability)

This is just a small sample here, there's many more examples if you would like to find more.

**Edit**: Oops, after some more Googling I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652657/1585957) with an answer that explains it very well.